# Click on button keeps the box moving for thrice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have below code where when I click the button, square box moves once. I need to move it further on second click. Again move it on third move. On fourth click it will reset to default position. I can getting a way. Can someone please help?

**Apex Page Code**

```
<apex:page showheader="false">
<!--  -->
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Start Animation</button>

<p>You are one move away to Complete!</p>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You need to increment the "left" on every click

Comment: Yes exactly! but how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding the current position to animate to is always moves from 0

There may be better ways but this works:

```
<apex:page showheader="false">
<!--  -->
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $div = $("div");
    $("button").click(function(){            
        var left = $div.position().left;
        if(left > 700){
            $div.animate({left: 0});
        }else{
            $div.animate({left:left + 250 });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Start Animation</button>

<p>You are one move away to Complete!</p>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It's moving perfectly, but I need it at default after third click. I need to register the no of clicks somewhere.

Comment: Updated. From this point you will need to do the rest as I believe I have answered this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    var leftPos = parseInt($("div").attr("left-position"));
    var pxl = 250;
    var final = leftPos + 250;
    alert(final);
        $("div").animate({left: final});
    $("div").attr("left-position", final);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Start Animation</button>

<p>You are one move away to Complete!</p>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;" left-position="0"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Create a html attribute to add the click count